# How to recover AWS ElasticBeanstalk OptionSettings

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I forgot to add OptionSettings file to git and accidentally reset my repo. It took me a while to get it setup to run (and was able to deployed before).

Does AWS save a copy of this file somewhere? If they do, where can I download it? It took me a while to figure thjs out so I don't want to have to redo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it should be in a file called .ebextensions/options.config in the zipped application version. If it was deployed you should be able to find it in the S3 bucket/path like this: s3://elasticbeanstalk-region-account/resources/environments/e-xxxxxxx/_runtime/_versions/app-name/app-name-version

Comment: It was not there in the app-name version but I found it under resources > templates